# how to install react-native-video on windows app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video, react-window, react-native-windows

for a certain windows app I am trying to install the react-native-video package on the solution project.
I found the following procedure :

[the image taken from the link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n11DQ.png)

but at the step " Add #include "winrt/ReactNativeVideoCPP.h"."
I'm getting an error: "cannot find the source code "ReactNativeVideoCPP.h"

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, because I assumed the include statement within pch.h should be in the same style as the others e.g.

```
#include <winrt/ReactNativeVideoCPP.h>
```

But if I followed the install instructions exactly, such as:

```
#include "winrt/ReactNativeVideoCPP.h"
```

This worked for me, as long as you follow the other install steps exactly.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done, but I'm still getting the same error. Is there something else that might cause the error?